# Crear una clase de un elemento webdriver en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo estas clases:

```
class BaseElement:
   def __init__(self, locator):
       self.locator = locator


class ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(BaseElement):
   def __init__(self, locator, element_to_appear_path):
        super(ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement, self).__init__(locator)
        self.element_to_appear_path = element_to_appear_path

   def __get__(self, obj, owner):
       driver = obj.driver
       element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(self.locator))
       element.click()
       WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located(self.element_to_appear_path))
```

Que estoy creando un elemento de esta forma:

```
class WorkerTimePage:
    timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago = ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement(
    (By.ID, "timesheet_id"),
    (By.XPATH, '//th[@class="workday"]'))
```

Es un proyecto para selenium en el que básicamente quiero crear un test en el que permita llamar a la variable `timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago` y haces las acciones que vienen en la clase `ButtonElementAndWaitNewElement`(en este caso solo hacer un click en un elemento webdriver y esperar un nuevo elemento), tengo la configuración de mi test de esta forma:

```
from cloud_testing.login.page_objects import LoginPage
from cloud_testing.test_base import TestBase
from cloud_testing.worker.page_objects import WorkerTimePage

class TestEditTimesheet(TestBase):

     login_page = None
     worker_time_page = None

     def setup_method(self):
         super(TestEditTimesheet, self).setup_method()
         self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
         self.worker_time_page = WorkerTimePage(self.driver)

     def test_worker_adds_punch_to_timesheet(self):
         self.login_page.login('bescoto@fgeneric.com', 'bescoto')
         self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()
```

Como lo tengo actualmente funciona en hacer las acciones que tengo en la clase pero al final manda este error:

```
self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

No estoy seguro que necesito cambiar para funcione lo que estoy buscando, cualquier ayuda es apreciada.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago()
```

Estás llamando a timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago cómo función pero lo declaraste como objeto.

```
self.worker_time_page.timesheet_from_3_weeks_ago.__get__(self.driver, owner)
```

No entiendo los parámetros que le mandas.